# Jquery mobile panel stops working after navigation between pages in multi page template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

In a multi page template setup in a jquery mobile application after leaving the first page via  panel navigation. When returning to the first page via another form of navigation the panel looks "hanged".

Looking closely you can see a small shadow to the left which is the hidden panel. The button to show the panel does no longer work.

Here is a demo that replicates the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <title>Panel Issue Demo</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="one">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>One</h1>
            <a href="#one-menu" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        </div>

        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" id="one-menu">
            <ul class="ui-listview ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Two</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="two">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Two</h1>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#one" data-ajax="false">One</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The steps to replicate are simple:

1. Open panel and click "Two"
2. Click "One"
3. Panel is now broken.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jVzNk/

Comment: Remove `data-ajax="false"` from links if you want to JQM to work properly in navigating between pages. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jVzNk/1/show/

Comment: Add data-animate="false" to div#one-menu. This disables the animation on the menu and your bug disappears. This appears to be caused by the complete callback on the close animation not being called for some reason when you display panel two. This should probably be filed as an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @Matt he navigates to pages with ajax disabled, enabling ajax solves the problem as in the demo on my first comment. JQM is base on Ajax navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is based on *Ajax Navigation* for switching between pages and loading new pages. When you link a page with `data-ajax="false"` you disable *Ajax Navigation* and jump/skip to that div as an *internal* div within the page.

To link between pages in jQuery Mobile, Ajax Navigation should be **enabled**.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <a href="#step3" data-ajax="false">Step 3</a>

  <div id="step1">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    <!-- You jump to this div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to use this in jQM but not for changing pages in *Multi-page model*. Also, use `data-ajax="false"` when you want to load page normally via HTTP not Ajax, and when you want to submit *forms*.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5fnM8/)**